# mecurial tortoiseHg exporting patch after commit

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I have successfully made patches before, but my most recent patch is empty. I have done two commits, and now I want to make a patch which includes the changes in those last two commits.

I tried selecting the earliest revision that I wanted in the patch, but nothing showed up in the commit tab (the check mark), and nothing was in the patch I created either.

Can I create a patch after I have committed, and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make patches after committing, just select both revisions, right-click and choose `Export Selected...`:

[image: TortoiseHG screenshot]

This will export one patch file for each patch:

[image: exported patches]

Comment: 1. OP wants aggregated patch 2. His **main** problem - empty commits